# Symbol not found - POSTGIS on PostgreSQL 9.3.3 Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgis

I have had some problems with upgrading from OS X 10.9 to 10.10. I have installed PostgreSQL and POSTGIS with homebrew. I tried to upgrade to PostgreSQL 9.4.4 but went back to 9.3.3 because I was not able to upgrade my database. I also reverted back to POSTGIS 2.1.1 (from 2.1.7). Now when I look at my pg database I can see the tables but when I try to browse records (with Navicat) I get this error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so": dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so, 10): Symbol not found: _json_tokener_errors
```

Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libjson-c.2.dylib
 in /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: "because I was not able to upgrade my database". Details? As for the error: Looks like that PostGIS lib is still compiled against 9.4.